# Run command from PHP script: sh: 1: screen: not found

Tags: php, linux, apache, suphp

I have problem with script that running screen session.

```
<?php  exec("screen -m -d ffmpeg2theora -v 3 /path/to/video.mp4");  ?>
```

and see this on logs:

```
Wed Oct 17 16:17:39 2012] [error] [client 83.5.x.x] sh: 1: screen: not found, referer: http://xxxxxx.xx
```

It's stop working on some update (apache/php/suphp?), before that was working like charm
Any idea's what's happend, how configure suPhp/Apache?

Comment: What happens when you run that same command from your command line?

Comment: It looks like your Path variables aren't set. So you'll need to run `which screen` which will give you the full path of the executable. Something that will look like `/usr/bin/screen`

Comment: @afuzzyllama when run script from from bash (php5-cli -f file.php) session is started and movie is converted

Comment: I think @james_t has the answer to your problem

Comment: Why do you want to use screen to do this anyway?

Comment: @Explosion Pills i don't want hold executing script until conversion is done. when video file is large php throw execution time error, but if you have any better idea to solve this i'm listening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want PHP to start a long-running command in the background, why not try the following:

```
<?php pclose(popen("/usr/bin/nohup /path/to/ffmpeg2theora -v 3 /path/to/video.mp4 >/tmp/result 2>&1", "r")); ?>
```

It's always wise to use explicit paths to commands in these sorts of situations.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, simply do:

```
exec("ffmpeg2theora -v 3 /path/to/video.mp4 &");
```